# Listview height based on items is greater than items height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout activity contains a list-view. I want to make the list-view height based on its items, I searched in the internet and found many methods do this but all methods give the list-view height greater than items height.
The method I use as following:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
            View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

when I debug the method If found that there are some items height equal to "45" and some items height equal to "66" while all items in the list-view have the same height when the activity appear.

Here is a snapshot of the activity, the list-view background is light-gray to show the list-view height:
[Activity snpapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBFDL.jpg)

Comment: Doing this pretty much defeats the purpose of using a `ListView`. Why don't you just use a vertical `LinearLayout` instead, with its `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`?

Comment: If you want to have list based view with different height, I think it is easier if you use RecyclerView rather than ListViwe

Answer (score 0):

if you want the whole list to be visible then don't use list view
listview is not made for this it's made to fill the screen and the reusing it's views

use a scrollview with linear and inflate them inside but the is a bad approach and will take a long time
so please revisit the reasons you are doing this maybe you will find a better Widget for it or maybe share a screenshot of the ui you are trying to achieve